# How to create a c array?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, pointers

How can I set a pointer to a C array in my constructor?

```
@implementation NSBufferedInputStream {
    char *buffer;
    int bufferSize;
}

- (id)initWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    self = [super initWithFileAtPath:path];
    if (self) {
        bufferSize = 100;
        buffer = char[bufferSize]; // ERROR: Expected expression
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: From a quick glance, I'd say its because c doesn't support dynamic arrays without using malloc or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly need a dynamically-sized array,

```
- (id)initWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    self = [super initWithFileAtPath:path];
    if (self) {
        bufferSize = 100;
        buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufferSize);
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    free(buffer);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Otherwise, if your array size is known at compile time, just change your ivar from `char *buffer;` to:

```
char buffer[100]
```

Comment: Why would you use dealloc if apple now has Automatic Reference Counting?

Comment: ARC cannot handle the freeing of your `malloc()` calls for you--if you use `malloc()`, you must use `free()`. So implementing `-dealloc` here is important--but if you are using ARC, you should *not* call `[super dealloc];` as that will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the array is dynamic - use `malloc`, if not, you need to do it at the declaration:

```
@implementation NSBufferedInputStream {
    char buffer[100];
    int bufferSize;
}
```

Comment: When you say dynamic, is it possible to increase the size of the array without copying its contents? That would be very useful. In this situation, I have a setBufferSize method in which I can change the buffer size before loading a file.

Comment: Would you know if NSMutableArray uses realloc? Currently I have a NSObject wrapper for my structs so I can use NSMutableArray and this is inefficient.